# struct cannot appear in a constant-expression; template arguments invalid

Tags: c++

This function is giving me errors such as:

error: 'vertice' cannot appear in a constant-expression

error: template argument 1 is invalid

error: `iterator' does not name a type

```
list< list<vertice> >::iterator extraiLista(string vertice, list< list<vertice> >& listaVertices){
    list< list<vertice> >::iterator itVert;

    for(itVert = listaVertices.begin(); itVert != listaVertices.end(); itVert++){
        list<vertice>::iterator aux = itVert->begin();
        if(aux->nome == vertice)
            return itVert;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

'vertice' is a struct that I created and I'm having no problems using it in other functions. It's just this one that is giving me trouble. I thought the problem might be with the iterator but I tried it in another function and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the function, `vertice` is the name of the function parameter, not the type which it hides.

To refer to the type, you can either elaborate it:

```
list<class vertice>
```

or qualify it:

```
list<::vertice>    // assuming it's in the global namespace
```

but it might be better to choose a different name for the parameter.

Comment: @Koz And I will recommend you to use type definitions for example: `typedef list<vertice> vertice_list_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You made at least two errors.

---

Error 1:

```
string vertice, list< list<vertice> >
```

"vertice" cannot be both a typename (as in `list<list<vertice> >`) and a variable (as in `string vertice`).

---

Error 2:

```
return NULL;
```

Your function returns `list<list<iterator> >`. In C++, `NULL` is `int`.  There is no casting from `int` to `list<list<iterator> >` .